# Can I get my .Net fastline graph to scroll leftward faster?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want 24 fastline graphs to all scroll leftward (like a 24 needle, scrolling paper graph).

But it's slow and lags behind.  I delete each leftmost point before adding each new rightmost point.

Is there a faster way to scroll leftward?

My Windows 10 laptop is a Core i9 with 128GM memory.

```vb
' My graph scrolls leftward.
' For each New value, I use .RemoveAt(0) to remove the leftmost point, and then use .AddXY to add the New point at the right.
' (I've assumed this is faster than .clear and re-plot entire graph.  Maybe I'm wrong.)


    Me.Chart_antenna_window.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount


for ...  ' 150 times
    Me.Chart_antenna_window.ResetAutoValues()   ' slows down if this is before 'do' or if it's downat the .addXY  Microsoft Docs on it is skimpy.
    . . .
for ... ' 24 times
    . . .

    plot_Points_Q = Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series(present_series_name & "_Q" & graph_freq_index).Points   ' 2ms
    plot_Points_I = Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series(present_series_name & "_I" & graph_freq_index).Points

    plot_Points_I.RemoveAt(0)                                                                                    ' 3ms
    plot_Points_I.AddXY(x_axis_point, antenna_amplitude_I)                                                       ' 2ms
    plot_Points_Q.RemoveAt(0)                                                                                    ' 2ms
    plot_Points_Q.AddXY(x_axis_point, antenna_amplitude_Q)
                x_axis_point += 1   

    ' ....................  all above takes 3ms
    . . .

    If   not end of this for next then  x_axis_point -= 1
next

next
```

Comment: Removing from a list is O(n) due to having to shift up the elements. In your case you are causing the worse case every time due to removing the very first item. Removing very last item does not incur this cost and is actually O(1). Rethink if you need the remove functionality or consider a different structure or some sort of circular buffer.

Comment: JohanP: Thanks. So you're saying it's faster to .clear and then .addXY all the elements again, instead of .RemoveAt oldest and .AddXY the newest.